# Compare NSDateComponents to integer (or convert NSDateComponents to integer)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I'm trying to check if X days passed from the app installation to unlock some features

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                    fromDate:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                                              objectForKey:@"firstTimeDate"]
                                                      toDate:now
                                                     options:0];
```

but when I do

```
if (!(components < 1)) {
 ...
}
```

I get

> Ordered comparison between pointer and integer ('NSDateComponents *' and 'int')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are asking for the number of days, you should access the `day` property.

```
if (components.day >= 1) {
}
```

Note: Using `x >= y` is probably clearer than using `!(x < y)`.

Comment: nice! days are incrementing at 00:00:00 or every 24 hours?

Comment: Try different values but I believe you will get 1 day if the two dates are 24 hours apart.